# The Joomla 'create a template' tutorial

Tags: html, css, joomla

I've recently downloaded Joomla using an instant download option, and now I'm looking to create my own templates. I went to http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/joomla15/joomla_create_template.htm and am trying to follow the tutorial but I've failed at the first hurdle... where it says:

> First, open the "templates" directory in your Joomla installation. Then create a subfolder in it named "tutorial_template". All the files of your template will reside in it.

The problem is I have no clue how to do this, where is the directory to start with? The only thing I know how to get up is the administrator's screen, in which I have to choose one of the stock templates, which would be great if I didn't care about my own designs...but obviously I'm looking to have my own HTML and CSS coding used instead.

How do I find where the folders are and how do I open them?

Answer (score 2):

You downloaded Joomla, and you presumably installed it on a server?

The folders being referred to in the tutorial are the folders and files residing on the server.  They are likely accessed through FTP.

If you wish to understand what these folders/files look like and don't have FTP access to your server, download Joomla itself:
http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=5696

Extract the zip file, and you will see exactly what files/folders are being referred to.